# jquery isotope horizontal elements overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope, horizontal-scrolling

i am trying todo a horizontal isotope and if you look at the following fiddle you can see the problem:

the elements are overlapping...

```
<div class="cal">
<div class="col">
    <div class="head">
        1                
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="container">
         <div class="shape">
             <div class="inner-wrapper">
                 <div class="event">
                     <div class="main-avatar">
                         <a href="#">
                             img <p style="display: inline; margin-left: 3px;">name</p>
                         </a>
                     </div>
                     <h5><a href="#">something</a></h5>
                 </div>
                 <p style="padding-bottom: 0px">home</p>
                 <p style="padding-bottom: 0px">9:00 AM-9:00 AM</p>
             </div>
             <div class="">
                 <a href="#">More...</a>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="shape">
             <div class="inner-wrapper">
                 <div class="event">
                     <div class="main-avatar">
                         <a href="#">
                             img <p style="display: inline; margin-left: 3px;">name</p>
                         </a>
                     </div>
                     <h5><a href="#">something</a></h5>
                 </div>
                 <p style="padding-bottom: 0px">home</p>
                 <p style="padding-bottom: 0px">9:00 AM-9:00 AM</p>
             </div>
             <div class="">
                 <a href="#">More...</a>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="shape">
             <div class="inner-wrapper">
                 <div class="event">
                     <div class="main-avatar">
                         <a href="#">
                             img <p style="display: inline; margin-left: 3px;">name</p>
                         </a>
                     </div>
                     <h5><a href="#">something</a></h5>
                 </div>
                 <p style="padding-bottom: 0px">home</p>
                 <p style="padding-bottom: 0px">9:00 AM-9:00 AM</p>
             </div>
             <div class="">
                 <a href="#">More...</a>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>                
</div>
```

[an example you can see and test](http://jsfiddle.net/XVqkC/2/)

The funny part is that if you resize the window isotope renders the elements correct...

is this a bug for isotope or am i doing something wrong?

any help would be great ...

thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you what the problem is, but I noticed it fixes itself when the window resizes, so I added this to your code:

```
$(window).resize();
```

[And now it works](http://jsfiddle.net/XVqkC/3/).